# how to switch node version to installled newer one (v14.15.4)

Tags: node.js, version, homebrew

how can i switch my node version to the newer one (v14.15.4) ? I have tried all solutions here from stackoverflow... but no success.

I have made the following steps:

1. npm cache clean -f
2. npm install -g n
3. n stable

I ask for support.

```
RalfsMacBookPro:~ ralfborde$ sudo n stable
   installed : v14.15.4 to /usr/local/bin/node
      active : v10.23.2 at /usr/local/opt/node@10/bin/node
```

my current version:

```
RalfsMacBookPro:~ ralfborde$ node -v
v10.23.2
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this for version-management:

```
sudo npm install n -g
```

Then try this to upgrade it

```
sudo n stable

     OR

sudo n latest
```